# Basis of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

How can you find a basis of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$?

I thought every element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}+c\sqrt{5}+d\sqrt{15}$ with $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ rational numbers, but I don't see why we have {$1,\sqrt{3}$} as basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$.

I also need a basis of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. I think that, because $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ is an algebraic element of $\Bbb{Q}$, we have that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}]$ (here, I use () for field and [] for ring)
and this is equal to the set of all polynomials over $\Bbb{Q}$ were you replace $X$ with $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, but then I'm stuck. Can someone explain me please how you can find in gerenal a basis of a field $K$ over $F$ (where $F \subset K$)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $ \sqrt{15} \times \sqrt{3}$? Hence, how can we write $ \sqrt{5}$ as $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$-linear combinations of $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: For the second question, consider $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha )$ where $ \alpha =\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thanks. Is there a general strategy?

Comment: @Lozenges, is it true we have the basis $1, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$? How can you be sure of this? I'm looking for something that always works.

Comment: @CalvinLin, that's $3\sqrt{5}$, now I understand, but in general I don't know how you can see in advance that $1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}$ is a 'too big' basis (and thus in fact not a basis)

Comment: In general, given $K\subseteq E\subseteq F$, if $\left\{u_i\right\}$ is a basis of $E$ over $K$, and $\left\{v_j\right\}$ is a basis of $F$ over $E$, then $\left\{u_iv_j\right\}$ is a basis of $F$ over $K$. So, in this case, we have that $\left\{1,\sqrt{2},\alpha ,\alpha \sqrt{2}\right\}$ is a basis

Comment: Oh, that's a nice result! Thank you

Comment: Do you also know how to solve my first question more general?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{15}\right)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{15}\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\right)=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}\right)$ based on the comment above (@CalvinLin)

Comment: thank you for the help